# How to set a background color for the viewController in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11

I have been trying to set a background color for the whole `viewController` in swiftUI but I have not able to. The view does not take the attribute `.backgroundColor` .

I have tried using the `.backgroundColor` attribute for the `viewController` in `sceneDelegate` too and it is not taking the attribute but it takes the `foregroundColor` attribute.

Comment: Now, this is the right time to be *specific*... when you say *"viewController"*, are you talking a `UIViewController`, a `UIView`, or a `View`? There's a *huge* difference between the first two, which are `UIKit` classes and require integration with SwiftUI, and the third, which is `SwiftUI` and a modifier like @rraphael gave you will work.

Comment: I'm assuming by viewController, Rakesh means the entire iPhone screen. I'm still confused if that is a window or a scene.

Answer (score 15):

So far, what I have found to work best is to create a ZStack at the top of the ContentView body and have the first layer a Color, that ignores the safe area. Apple defines a Color as "a late-binding token", whatever that is, but it behaves similar to any other View.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.red
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

      /// Your Inner View content goes here.
      VStack {
        Text("Hello") 
      } // VStack

    } // ZStack
  } // body View
}  // ContentView
```

Note: Be careful about what is inside the Inner View because it can easily expand to fill the entire window thus overlaying your background color with white, etc. For example, the popular **NavigationView** tends to expand to the entire window and for me it tends to ignore its documented .background() setting. You can do the same ZStack strategy here too.

```
NavigationView {
  ZStack { 
    Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) 
    VStack {
      Text("Hello")
    } // VStack
  } // ZStack
}  // NavigationView
```

Comment: This didn't work for me with NavigationView that has a List.

Comment: Remember that a List is a view which then is loaded on top of the NavigationView and similarly expands to fill the screen. For example, if inside your NavigationView you have List {Text("Hello")}.opacity(0.2) you will see the background shine through. Thus, you will need to style the List View itself. Here is a StackOverflow question on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517904/how-do-i-modify-the-background-color-of-a-list-in-swiftui

Answer (score 3):

If you use the background modifier (.background(Color.red)) on the top view, you just will be wrapping that view with a new view with background color red around his padding or size. 
So you should use a Rectangle() view and a Z stack to set a full background to the whole view, and if you need, use the .edgesIgnoringSafeArea

```
    NavigationView {
        ZStack { 
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ScrollView {
                List()
                    ForEach(modelExampleList) { modelExample in
                        Row(model: modelExample)
                    }
                }.frame(height: 200)
            }.padding(.leading, 10)
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("ModelExample List"), displayMode: .large)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code for change whole of view controller color

```
ZStack {
        Color.red
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
```

and use this code for change safe area background color

```
ZStack {
        Color.red
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved it out of the `ZStack`, then used an `overlay` and it worked.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        sceneBackgroundColor
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .overlay(myView)
    }
}
```