# Make SwiftUI navigation bar transparent

Tags: uinavigationbar, swiftui

I'm searching for a way to make the NavigationBar transparent. My NavigationView is in the root view in ContentView which contains a TabView.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    TabView {
       HomeView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
            Text("Home")
        }.tag(1)
        NavigationView {
        SearchView()
            }

        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            Text("Search")
        }.tag(2)
}
```

The NavigationView Bar displays even after adding the following modifier in the root view.

```
init() { 
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().isHidden = false
```

}

Below is the child view in which I'm trying to hide the navigationbar background.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FacilityView: View {


var perks = "Badge_NoPerks"
var image = "Image_Course6"
var courseName = "Course"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 260)
        }
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Image(perks)
            }
            HStack {
                Text(courseName)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        Spacer()
    }.padding(.horizontal)
       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
      .navigationBarTitle("Facility Details")


}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to make the *entire* bar transparent, foreground and all? (I'm asking because you tried the `isHidden` modifier.)

Comment: Just the background. I need to keep the ability for someone to tap "Back"

Comment: Ow. This question *may* help, but I'm not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508983/how-to-set-navigationview-background-colour-in-swiftui

Answer (score 29):

iOS 16+:

`.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)`

Comment: Works on iOS 17.

Answer (score 21):

Try adding these to your init() modifiers:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

It worked for me in Xcode 11.2.1, iOS 13.2

Comment: It seems that there is no need to set `barTintColor`. just setting `backgroundImage` will do the trick.

Comment: Toobad this is global.I only want to do this on the home screen

Comment: I would also add the shadowImage to this logic because else you will see a line after the transparent navigation bar.

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()

Answer (score 11):

You can use this extension to UINavigationBar to toggle between transparent and default appearance.

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    static func changeAppearance(clear: Bool) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        
        if clear {
            appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        } else {
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        }
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

and in your view structs:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.changeAppearance(clear: true)
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this worked for me it would fix all my problems. But seems like its not having any affect on the navigation bar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LateNate I've revised the answer to put it as an extension.  Try this in your struct and see if it works.  Works fine for me.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks so much. This is great!

Comment: Be careful with this approach. SwiftUI sometimes inits structs for screens that aren't visible, for example when pointed to by a NavigationLink.

Comment: Is there any work around that we can use this in other part apart from init like changing during scrolling

Answer (score 6):

For a transparent background without shadow:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

If the first solution does not work then:

```
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
    appearance.shadowColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score -5):

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text("View1")
                .navigationBarHidden(false)
                .navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE: 1.9.2022

```swift
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
        Text("View1")

    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .toolbar{
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            Text("Title")
                .opacity(0.5)
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution can only work if you do not have any vertical scrollable view.

Comment: Just replace your Text with List of simple Texts

Comment: This is just a view (Color.red) in back order of content, not a transparent NavigationView.

Comment: @jason-tremain I added another solution.