# SwiftUI Navigation Bar Color

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to remove the translucent color of navigation bar in **SwiftUI**.

[image]

In the picture you can see, that the color of **nav** bar is not the same like below.
How is it possible, that the navigation bar has the same color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make SwiftUI navigation bar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616430/make-swiftui-navigation-bar-transparent)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your init() modifiers:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "whatever"))
```