# Screen Background Color With ScrollView And Navigation Bar SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, colors, swiftui

Im trying to have a colored background while using a scrollview with SwiftUI but this causes the navigation title to no longer collapse. I've tried a number of ways yet this is always an issue.

```
struct Person : Identifiable{
    var id : Int
    var name : String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let people = [
        Person(id: 1, name: "Ricky"),
        Person(id: 2, name: "Dani"),
        Person(id: 3, name: "Mark"),
        Person(id: 4, name: "Kailin"),
        Person(id: 5, name: "James"),
        Person(id: 5, name: "Jenna")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Color.red
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                ScrollView{
                    ForEach(people, id: \.id) { person in
                        Text(person.name)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Home")
            }
        }
    }

    //    init(){
    //        UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = .orange
    //    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Rearrange your views like this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                VStack {
                    ForEach(people, id: \.id) { person in
                        Text(person.name)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
```

---

#### From iOS 16

You can change the color of the navigation bar natively with the following modifier:

```
.toolbarBackground(.yellow, in: .navigationBar)
```

<sub>This works only on inline navigation bar (with a seamless animation)</sub>

#### **iOS 15** and below

You can use `UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red` alongside with another `UIColor` like `Color(UIColor.red)` for the background to simulate the transparent large `NavigationBar` until the direct API for changing the proper colors in SwiftUI arrives.

---

**NOTE 1:** `UIColor.red` is slightly different with `Color.red`.

**NOTE 2:** if you want to use a `List` instead of `ScrollView`, you should add `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` to `ZStack` to get rid of the extra white space.

Comment: Perfect thanks! The only downside to this is that if you change scrollview to list, the list adds padding creating white space.

Comment: Then add `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` to `ZStack`.

Comment: With this code, the statusbar still remains white, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, we don’t touch the statusbar color here at all

Comment: also ignoring the edges doesn't work here. So the top and bottom of the scrollview is still white. Which doesn't solve the problem. Not sure why making the background color is so hard in swiftUI

Comment: Is there any way to get the same effect (background on the scroll view without the header bug) with an image as opposed to a color?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with... this solution also allows you to colour the background cells a different colour to your List Elements. You could do a very similar thing with ScrollView

As mentioned in the comments for the other solution, carrying out that solution with ListView leaves a bunch of whitespace from the cells. (Which is why this is useful)

I thought I would add to this as none of the other solutions worked for me.

```
struct ListBackgroundColor: ViewModifier {

    let color: UIColor

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear() {
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = self.color
                //(Optional) Edit colour of cell background
                UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = self.color
            }
    }
}   

extension View {
    func listBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: ListBackgroundColor(color: color))
    }

}
```

UI Example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5PXt.jpg