# ScrollView with background breaks navigation header

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ScrollView embedded in a NavigationView, and I'd like to set the background (behind everything). I'm using the following code:

```
ScrollView{
        VStack{
            HStack{
               ...
            }
            .padding()
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .fill(Color(colorScheme == .dark ? .secondarySystemBackground : .systemBackground))
                    .shadow(radius: 4)
            ).padding()
        }
    }
    .background(
        Image("login-bg").resizable().scaledToFill().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    )
```

But it causes the navigation title to no longer collapse.

[image]

I've seen [Screen Background Color With ScrollView And Navigation Bar SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835597/screen-background-color-with-scrollview-and-navigation-bar-swiftui)
but the solution there didn't work for me. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: why don't you align RoundedRectangle y center & x center?
with background color clear.

Comment: are you saying not to use a scrollview? I could for the login page, but for the sign up screen (which uses the same layout), there's too much to show on the screen, so it has to be in a scrollview.

Comment: No I didn't mean that I'm asking u to try that uivew by aligning x n y center then see what happens