# SwiftUI how to get dynamic color?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5, xcode11

I have a config file and I want to change colors there. But in my view function background(bg1Color) gives me error;

> Argument type 'UIColor' does not conform to expected type 'View'

How can I fix this?

My config file;

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

// Backgrounds
var bg1Color: UIColor = .black
```

My function codes;

```
.background(bg1Color) // HERE
.cornerRadius(10)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437036/swiftui-how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.background` modifier takes a `View` and unlike **SwiftUI**'s `Color`, **UIKit**'s `UIColor` is not conformed to `View` protocol (by default).

So you need to create a `Color` from your `UIColor` and then pass it to the `.background` modifier.

```
.background(Color(bg1Color))
```

or directly:

```
.background(Color(.black))
```

---

## Very Important Note!

`UIColor` and `Color` *predefined named colors* are not the same! And they have different shades!

[image: Example]

So you should **NOT** just replace `UIColor` with `Color`.

<sub>Actually `SwiftIUI.Color.red` quals to `UIKit.UIClor.systemRed`</sub>

Comment: Wait... what? I never realised the SwiftUI.Color and UIColor did not make the same shades. Is this true if you use RGB initialiser too?

Comment: I meant for predefined named colors as I mentioned in the image. If you manually pass the values, they will be the same of course.

Comment: Ah, ok. Haha, that makes more sense. For a second there I thought you meant they were using different colour spaces. 

Comment: Actually `SwiftIUI.Color.red` quals to `UIKit.UIClor.systemRed`

Answer (score 1):

It's `Color` not `UIColor`

```
 import SwiftUI

 var bg1Color : Color = .black
```