# How can I set an image tint in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to set an image tint in SwiftUI `Image` class

For UIKit, I can set image tint using

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "cart")!.withTintColor(.blue)
```

but I cant find such settings in swiftui docs

Answer (score 119, accepted):

On new `swiftUI` for set `tint` use:

```
Image("ImageName")
  .foregroundColor(.red)
```

Depending on the source image you may also need an additional rendering mode modifier:

```
Image("ImageName")
  .renderingMode(.template)
  .colorMultiply(.red)
// or
Image("ImageName")
  .colorMultiply(.blue)
```

And you can read this [topic](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-adjust-views-by-tinting-and-desaturating-and-more).

Comment: Depending on the source image you may also need an additional rendering mode modifier:

`Image("ImageName").renderingMode(.template).colorMultiply(.red)`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that depending on if you are in light or dark mode, template images may start as black and .colorMultiply will have no. color multiply gives different results based on the original color of the image.

Comment: For some reason, if I use `renderingMode` + `colorMultiply` some colors where behaving weird (e.g. white was becoming blue). So I just replaced `colorMultiply` with `foregroundColor`. Final result: `Image("ImageName").renderingMode(.template). foregroundColor(.red)`

Comment: Thanks for `colorMultiply()`! This works where `tint` and `foregroundColor` do not.

Answer (score 79):

This worked for me,

```
Image("ImageName")
   .renderingMode(.template)
   .foregroundColor(.white)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it works in both light and dark mode.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me

Comment: the only worked for me also

Answer (score 12):

### Blending modes

For tinting, you can use the `.blendMode` modifier to composite your image with another image or with color. There are 20+ Photoshop-like blending modes in Xcode 14.0+. The most appropriate SwiftUI's blending modes for tinting are:

- .softLight
- .overlay
- .luminosity
- .screen

[image]

You'll get different results than you see here if you change the brightness and saturation of the blending color.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Gradient(colors: [.red, .yellow]))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Image("XcodeIcon")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .blendMode(.softLight)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**SwiftUI 4.x:**

**Approach 1:**

```
Image("your_image_name")
    .resizable()
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
Image("your_image_name")
  .resizable()
  .renderingMode(.template)
  .colorMultiply(.red)
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is probably the best one although this would work too:

```
let uiImage = UIImage(systemName: "cart")!.withTintColor(.blue)
let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
```

Then you can use the constant named `image` with SwiftUI.

Comment: You might need to declare `uiImage` globally. I did it like that and it worked for me.