# How to set the color of a NavigationView symbol button

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

My currently have a NavigationView with an embedded `ToolbarItemGroup` containing buttons with SF Symbols. I'm attempting to change the Trash button's color to that of red.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .navigationTitle("Today")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Add button was tapped")
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(.add)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Trash button was tapped")
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(.trash)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .accentColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .accentColor(.red)
                }
            }
    }
    
    
}
```

I can't seem to set the color of the Trash image symbol to red. `Image(.trash)` is no typo, I'm using [this extension](https://gist.github.com/revblaze/b999020df1452f654c5b4af45a00ab3d) I wrote!

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set an image tint in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152480/how-can-i-set-an-image-tint-in-swiftui)

Comment: Unfortunately not. None of the solutions seem to affect NavigationView symbols.

Comment: Does [using an inline menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027625/14956277) with a custom style work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `.accentColor(.red)` to the `NavigationView`. Although it will change the color of all `ToolBar` Items. An example would be

```
NavigationView {
 SomeViews
}
.accentColor(.red)
```

It did the trick, as shown here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An other way to work on NavigationView. Although it will change the color of all ToolBar Items, too.

```
struct ContentView: View {

   init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.magenta
   }

   // your code follows
}
```