# SwiftUI: background color for whole screen and not simple view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to do something very simple, display a view with a background color, and in the center of this view, display a single label.

I tried this:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello!")
    }
    .background(MyColors.blue)
    .ignoresSafeArea() 
}
```

Here is the given result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437036/swiftui-how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - How do I change the background color of a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437036/swiftui-how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-view)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working with this code:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Style.Color.red
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!")
        }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

I didn't understand first that background and rest of the view must be set on a different z-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Text("Hello!")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(MyColors.blue)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
```

Source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/224/common-swiftui-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them