# Fill safe area with color

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to fill the remaining white space with one color but i can't find any way to do that and i'm beginner on ios development

Photo of my app:

[image]

Comment: Use `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` to ignore safe areas. From there, you can calculate the size of the safe area using GeometryReader.

Comment: https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/navigation-bar-styling-in-swiftui

Comment: Edit your question and post your code used to generate this view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - How do I change the background color of a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437036/swiftui-how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your content into a `ZStack` and use a view with `.ignoresSafeArea(.all)` as background.

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GradientBackground(colors: [.red, .green])
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Setttings")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(16)
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GradientBackground: View {
    let colors: [Color]
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: colors), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the property .ignoresSafeArea() on your view can expand the boundaries of your settings view outside of the safe areas.

The documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/ignoressafearea(_:edges:))

Comment: But this might also affect child views and preventing TextField from respecting it, more precisely the bottom one and end up being covered by the keyboard.